# Search about word in BST using Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I want to check if the word is exist in the BST or not.

There is a mistake it gives me `false` always:

```
if(listOfWords.contain(word))
write.print(word+" ");
// using this method but it does not work

private boolean contain(englishWord list, String word) {
    if (list != null) {
        contain(list.getLeft(), word);
        if (word.equals(list.getWord())) {
            return true;
        }
        contain(list.getRight(), word);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is the Binary search tree from a specific library or have you written it yourself? Is it actually null?

Comment: @Angzuril i wrote it by myself and i want to write a search method

Comment: That makes sense, I had missed the actual error and thought it might be be the BST itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return true` statement is lost up the order in recursion.

You can use something like,

```
if (list != null) {
    if (word.equals(list.getWord()) || contain(list.getLeft(), word) || contain(list.getRight(), word)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

But this will take `O(n)` time complexity. And a BST is designed to give much better performances than that.

If your BST is arranged as it should have been, something like this should work (and will be more efficient than your algorithm).

```
if (list != null) {
    int compare = word.compareTo(list.getWord());
    if (compare == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (compare > 0) {
        return contain(list.getRight(), word);
    } else {
        return contain(list.getLeft(), word);
    }
}
return false;
```